# Locking a File Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I found the below script to help me lock a file for a certain amount of time.

```
$Path = "E:\status.txt"
$Mode = "Open"
$Access = "Read"
$Share = "None"

Function lockit() {
  Param([String]$Path, [String]$Mode, [String]$Access, $Share)
  $File = [System.IO.File]::Open($Path, $Mode, $Access, $Share) 
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 50
  $File.Close()
}
```

The issue here is the PowerShell script runs and terminates after 50 seconds but for those 50 seconds, the PS session is active. I would like to be able to execute this PowerShell script and return control to the calling script immediately.

The execution needs to be asynchronous.
Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: I sense an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. Why do you think you need a lock on that file? What are you trying to accomplish by obtaining that lock?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers' valid point aside, you can use `Start-Job` to run scripts asynchronously or, if no error handling or monitoring is required, `Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers the problem I'm trying to solve is this, I want to lock a file and then run some tests with an application that tries to access the file for reads, for writes etc. This script will aid in testing my application.

Comment: Then I'd use a background job (`Start-Job`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, It looks like I need to use Start-Process. Start-Job is only valid as long as the PS Session i.e. PS Window remains active.

Comment: Use `Start-Job` in the script that is running the tests. You may want to consider using Pester as a testing framework.